# How to execute javascript placed inside href of a tags

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

can any one help me for web scraping, I want to fetch the data from url with contain multiple pages, with unchanged url.

I tried with beautiful soup, but with that i am able to get the first page data only.

```
html = urlopen(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
df = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
for x in df:
    exxxx = js2py.eval_js(x['href'])
```

Tried using js2py, didn't work.

Comment: if page uses javascript to change content on page then you may have to use `Selenium` to control web browser which runs JavaScript. Or you my try to use `DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox to find url used by JavaScript to get new data from server and then use this url in your code.

Comment: additionally, it is possible the data is within `<script>` tags in json format, and as stated, you could find (if it's available) the url request to the specific server . Without having the url though that you are getting page 1 from, we wouldn't be able to help beyond what is stated in mine or furas' comments

Comment: please provide the source url if possible

Comment: Thanx for your help